# After dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO, the parent view controller can't handle rotation any more

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I run into a strange problem. From the main view controller, I present a modal view controller using

[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];

Howeve after the modal view controller is dismissed with dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO, the main view controller can't handle rotation any more (it no longer rotates).

How to resolve this?

Comment: rotate means? orientation change?

Comment: Try [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]; because [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO]; is deprecated.